# Unable to add new modules in Joomla 3.2 after upgrading

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla3.0

I did a direct migration from Joomla 1.5.26 to Joomla 3.2.3 using SPUpgrade and I didn’t get any errors.

But the problem now is that I am unable to add menu modules for the menus. I am able to delete modules but not able to add any new ones to any positions.

I tried following the steps from the article below:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/menu/create-menu-and-module

but I do all these steps , but I don’t see any new modules being added in the list of new modules in the Module Manager.

Is there any other step , I may have missed?

Comment: Have you tried creating the menu module on its own and in the module settings making it point to the menu you want?

Comment: Yes, same thing. I follow all the steps but nothing gets added to the existing list

Comment: Can you please look at your database table and see if the new module is appearing in the modules table after you create it? Also please check that a row is created for it in the assets table.